# Blazor WASM 6.0.0-preview.7.21378.6, Visual Studio 2022 preview 3.1

Tags: blazor-webassembly, visual-studio-2022

I created a standard Blazor WASM project from the template with individual user accounts, ASP.NET Hosted, and Configured for Https, Progressive Web Application checked.

Running the project, I get this in the Dev Tools:

`crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not load settings from '_configuration/Wtf.Client'
createUserManager@https://localhost:44344/_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication/AuthenticationService.js:2:288346

Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Could not load settings from '_configuration/Wtf.Client'
createUserManager@https://localhost:44344/_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication/AuthenticationService.js:2:288346

at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.d__16`1[[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext() in Microsoft.JSInterop.dll:token 0x60000b3+0x156 at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntimeExtensions.InvokeVoidAsync(IJSRuntime jsRuntime, String identifier, Object[] args) in Microsoft.JSInterop.dll:token 0x6000049+0x84 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationService`3.d__27[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationState, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteUserAccount, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.ApiAuthorizationProviderOptions, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].MoveNext() in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.dll:token 0x6000122+0x95
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationService`3.<GetAuthenticatedUser>d__26[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationState, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteUserAccount, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.ApiAuthorizationProviderOptions, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].MoveNext() in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.dll:token 0x6000120+0x7d at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationService`3.d__25[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationState, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteUserAccount, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.ApiAuthorizationProviderOptions, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].MoveNext() in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.dll:token 0x600011e+0xa7
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationService`3.d__17[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationState, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteUserAccount, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.ApiAuthorizationProviderOptions, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].MoveNext() in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.dll:token 0x6000110+0x63
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthorizeViewCore.OnParametersSetAsync() in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.dll:token 0x6000043+0xfd
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task) in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll:token 0x60000a5+0x7e
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync() in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll:token 0x60000a3+0x113
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState) in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll:token 0x6000285+0x65 blazor.webassembly.js:1:30848
Cookie “PHPSESSID” will be soon treated as cross-site cookie against “https://localhost:44344/css/open-iconic/font/fonts/open-iconic.woff” because the scheme does not match. open-iconic.woff
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not load settings from '_configuration/Wtf.Client'
createUserManager@https://localhost:44344/_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication/AuthenticationService.js:2:288346

Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Could not load settings from '_configuration/Wtf.Client'
createUserManager@https://localhost:44344/_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication/AuthenticationService.js:2:288346

at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.d__16`1[[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext() in Microsoft.JSInterop.dll:token 0x60000b3+0x156 at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntimeExtensions.InvokeVoidAsync(IJSRuntime jsRuntime, String identifier, Object[] args) in Microsoft.JSInterop.dll:token 0x6000049+0x84 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationService`3.d__27[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationState, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteUserAccount, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.ApiAuthorizationProviderOptions, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].MoveNext() in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.dll:token 0x6000122+0x95
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationService`3.<GetAuthenticatedUser>d__26[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationState, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteUserAccount, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.ApiAuthorizationProviderOptions, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].MoveNext() in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.dll:token 0x6000120+0x7d at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationService`3.d__25[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationState, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteUserAccount, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.ApiAuthorizationProviderOptions, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].MoveNext() in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.dll:token 0x600011e+0xa7
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationService`3.d__17[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationState, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteUserAccount, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.ApiAuthorizationProviderOptions, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].MoveNext() in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.dll:token 0x6000110+0x63
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthorizeViewCore.OnParametersSetAsync() in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.dll:token 0x6000043+0xfd
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task) in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll:token 0x60000a5+0x7e
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState) in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll:token 0x6000285+0x65 blazor.webassembly.js:1:30848
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not load settings from '_configuration/Wtf.Client'
createUserManager@https://localhost:44344/_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication/AuthenticationService.js:2:288346

Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Could not load settings from '_configuration/Wtf.Client'
createUserManager@https://localhost:44344/_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication/AuthenticationService.js:2:288346

at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.d__16`1[[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext() in Microsoft.JSInterop.dll:token 0x60000b3+0x156 at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntimeExtensions.InvokeVoidAsync(IJSRuntime jsRuntime, String identifier, Object[] args) in Microsoft.JSInterop.dll:token 0x6000049+0x84 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationService`3.d__27[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationState, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteUserAccount, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.ApiAuthorizationProviderOptions, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].MoveNext() in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.dll:token 0x6000122+0x95
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationService`3.<GetAuthenticatedUser>d__26[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationState, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteUserAccount, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.ApiAuthorizationProviderOptions, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].MoveNext() in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.dll:token 0x6000120+0x7d at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationService`3.d__25[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationState, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteUserAccount, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.ApiAuthorizationProviderOptions, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].MoveNext() in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.dll:token 0x600011e+0xa7
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationService`3.<GetAuthenticationStateAsync>d__17[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationState, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteUserAccount, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.ApiAuthorizationProviderOptions, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].MoveNext() in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.dll:token 0x6000110+0x63 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthorizeViewCore.OnParametersSetAsync() in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.dll:token 0x6000043+0xfd at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task) in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll:token 0x60000a5+0x7e at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync() in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll:token 0x60000a3+0x113 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState) in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll:token 0x6000285+0x65`

Anyone know what's happening here? I did install "The Essentials" extension by Mads Kristensen, if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a Hosted Wasm project in VS2020 preview the default start project is set to the Client. That kind-of works for a simple app (no Auth) but it probably is a litle bug.

The simple fix is to right-click on the Server project and select "Set as Startup Project".

Comment: It's amazing how many details go into getting the tooling, the templates, etc right for GA. Can't wait for .NET 6!! Thank you.